# Counting number of selected columns with valid (not missing) values (R)

Tags: r

I want to create a column that counts the cases where the value is not missing in the selected columns.

Here is the code:

```
a <- c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "", NA)
b <- c("", NA, "aa", "", "", "dd")
c <- c("aa", "", NA, NA, "cc", "dd")
d <- c("aa", "bb", "", NA, "cc", "dd")
data <- data.frame(cbind(a,b,c,d))

data$cases <- rowSums(nchar(as.matrix(data))>1, na.rm = TRUE)
```

I would like to take only columns **"b"** and **"c"** into account. How do I complete the code?

Comment: `rowSums(nchar(as.matrix(data[, c("b", "c")]))>1, na.rm = TRUE)`? Or probably safer without `as.matrix`. I.e. `rowSums(sapply(data[, c("b", "c")], nchar)>1, na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
a <- c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "", NA)
b <- c("", NA, "aa", "", "", "dd")
c <- c("aa", "", NA, NA, "cc", "dd")
d <- c("aa", "bb", "", NA, "cc", "dd")
data <- data.frame(cbind(a,b,c,d))

library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(purrr)

data %>% 
  mutate(cases = across(c(b, c), \(x) !(is.na(x) | x == "")) %>% reduce(`+`))
#>      a    b    c    d cases
#> 1   aa        aa   aa     1
#> 2   bb <NA>        bb     0
#> 3   cc   aa <NA>          1
#> 4   dd      <NA> <NA>     0
#> 5             cc   cc     1
#> 6 <NA>   dd   dd   dd     2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>